# Create UI like Window 8 in vb.net using devexpress controls

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, windows-8, devexpress

I want to create UI for home page like a Window 8 for desktop application in vb.net using devexpress controls. How can I design the UI?

And I want to use `TileLayoutControl` for it. But I don't know how to use the tile controls of `devexpress`. How can I create my home page like Window8 Home page? I want to put various menus on home page as a Tile and when I click on 1 menu the form should be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `desktop application` is equals to `WinForms/WPF application` in the context of this question.
So, with DevExpress WinForms you can start from here: [DocumentManager Windows UI View Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11358).
Please also check the [Windows UI View Examples](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11854).

With DevExpress WPF Controls you can start from here: [Windows UI controls for WPF Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15018).
Please also check the [Windows UI controls for WPF Examples](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15024).

If you mean the Windows Store(WinRT) application please use the [DevExpress Windows 8 XAML Controls](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinRT/). Check the [Windows 8 XAML Controls Getting Started](http://help.devexpress.com/#XAML/CustomDocument12047).

**Updated**

[WinForms TileControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument14877)
[WPF TileControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11541)

Comment: From where I get Tile Control ?

Comment: There are no tile control in devexpress controls

Comment: The type 'dxlc:Tile' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani You should add all needed xml namespaces to use dxlc:Tile: `xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"`

Comment: @ChetanSanghani [How to: Create a Tile Layout Control](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10996)

Comment: @ChetanSanghani It is very strange... Ensure that you are references all needed assemblies. And try [this training video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVmF9_BGHoM)

Comment: I am using devexpress 11 . And there are no tile and layout control in it. There are only layout controls in it.Tile and layout control is in devexpress 13

Comment: @ChetanSanghani As far as i know the TileControl(for Win) was introduced in v11.2 and the TileControl (for WPF) was introduced in v12.1. Thus you should not use v11.1. Please update to the latest version.